# "No overload matches" my Object.assign() call; how can I fix it?

Tags: typescript

```js
export class Attributes<T> {
    constructor(private data: T) {}

    get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
        return this.data[key];
    }

    set(update: T): void {
        Object.assign(this.data, update);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of an error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZuG0.png)

and text version

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(target: {}, source: T): {} & T', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(target: object, ...sources: any[]): any', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.ts(2769)
Attributes.ts(1, 25): This type parameter might need an `extends {}` constraint.
Attributes.ts(1, 25): This type parameter might need an `extends object` constraint.
```

Comment: Seems perfectly normal behaviour `Object.assign()` expects an object as the first parameter and there is no guarantee `T` would be an object. Consider `new Attributes<number>(42);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As error says:

```
This type parameter might need an `extends object` constraint.
```

So you should constraint `T` to extend the `object`, which will means that it is not a primitive:

```
class Attributes<T extends object> {
  constructor(private data: T) {}

  get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
    return this.data[key];
  }

  set(update: T): void {
    Object.assign(this.data, update); // no error
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. In the end any problem can be fixed by slowly reading an error